# I'm using the ta.lowest function to calculate a stop loss and take profit. Though I want these to become a static fixed number when trade is executed

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm using the ta.lowest and ta.highest function to calculate a stop loss and take profit. Though I want these to become a static fixed number when trade is executed. So on a long trade, im trying to put my stop at the low of the past 10 days, and the take profit a multiple of that. Though when the trade executes, these numbers continue to calculate off the past bars and move with price (as they should). Is there a way I can make these a static number when the trade has been executed?

```
high10 = ta.highestbars(10)

low10 = ta.lowest(low, 10)

takeProfit = ((close - low10) * 2) + close


longCondition = ta.crossover(EMA_fast, EMA_slow)

longExitCondition = ta.crossunder(EMA_fast, EMA_slow)

longExitCondition1 = takeProfit

if longCondition
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
    stopLoss = low10
    strategy.exit("exit", "long", loss=stopLoss)
    
    

if high >= longExitCondition1
    strategy.close(id="long")
```

Answer (score 1):

we can use `var` to prevent recalculation of values from bar to bar. Variables declared with `var` initialize on the first bar at runtime, and hold their values, unless we dictate another value. New values can be assigned to a variable later in the script using the `:=` operator. Here I have taken your script and added a stop and a limit declaring them with `var`. They are assigned under the entry condition. I also plotted them so you can see them and included notes for descriptions of the changes.

Cheers and best of luck with your coding and trading

```
EMA_fast = ta.ema(close, 9)
EMA_slow = ta.ema(close, 21)

// declare 2 variables with `var` which sets them to 0 on first bar and will not recalculate until we "set" them
var stopLoss   = 0.0
var takeProfit = 0.0

long = strategy.position_size > 0 // a variable to check if we are in a long position 

high10 = ta.highestbars(10)

low10 = ta.lowest(low, 10)

takeProfitCalc = ((close - low10) * 2) + close

longCondition = ta.crossover(EMA_fast, EMA_slow)

longExitCondition = ta.crossunder(EMA_fast, EMA_slow)

// we need to check that we are not already long otherwise we may "set" our limits again mid-trade if the condition were to occur before the trade is through
if longCondition and not long
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
    stopLoss   := low10
    takeProfit := takeProfitCalc  // Here we use `:=` to "set" the variables under the entry condition

strategy.exit("exit", "long", stop = stopLoss, limit = takeProfit) // we use the `stop` and `limit` args to enter our levels 

drawOrders = long or longCondition // condition to check when to draw lines. we only want them when in, or entering a position

plot(drawOrders or drawOrders[1] ? stopLoss   : na, "Stop Loss",   color.red   ,style = plot.style_linebr) // we use the draworders cond to draw lines on the exit bar too 
plot(drawOrders or drawOrders[1] ? takeProfit : na, "Take Profit", color.green ,style = plot.style_linebr) // note the plot style. this allows breaks in the lines when not in pos.

// optional close if cross back down
// if longExitCondition
//     strategy.close(id="long")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that, there was almost a computer shaped hole in my office window. The help is vey much appreciated.